# Where is the GeoRSS feature?

Tags: openlayers

I need to show a GeoRSS in OL3 but I can't find the correct way.

I want to do this:

http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/georss.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no GeoRSS serializer included in Openlayers 3+.
You can use third parties library to convert GeoRSS to other compatible formats like GeoJSON.

I've choose to use [GeoRSSToGeoJSON](https://github.com/yohanboniface/GeoRSSToGeoJSON) (Github repo, also available using npm e.g https://www.npmjs.com/package/georsstogeojson)

I've done [a demo](https://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/36df7f071918ca5ec6ec78b5f442458d) to take the GeoRSS, convert it to GeoJSON and add it to the map.